# Regex match for character not in quotes or escaped quotes

Tags: .net, regex

Hi I'm trying to write a regex statement to match a "`{`" character only if it is not in cased in quotes.

I then need to return (replace line) with everything (if anything) to the right of the character.

Similarly I need to do the same with the "`}`" character but return everything on the left. These need to be separate regex.

As an example:

```
if { something
```

Should MATCH and return " `something`"

```
if { " something
```

Should MATCH and return " `" something`"

```
" if { " something
```

Should **NOT MATCH** and not return anything

Comment: What have you tried so far? Google look ahead and look behind and it should be simple enough

Comment: In the title, you write "not in quotes or escaped quotes". What do you mean by that - should escaped quotes be treated like unescaped quotes, or should they be disregarded? Also, could there be quotes in comments (if so, what kind of comments, and how should they be treated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't something the .Net implementation of regex can do without running into edge cases. You'll need to use a parser to do it properly. A basic state machine pattern where that iterates along the string and flips state when it hits the characters you're looking for.